# Is it allowed to use the quadratic solution formula for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, simulation, simulink

I have some trouble with a challenging fluid mechanics problem. The problem leads me to a non-linear ode 1st order.

$0={\dot p_C}^2+\frac{k_1}{k_2 C}\dot p_C+\frac{p_C-p_0}{k_2C^2}$

My Idea was now to change the equation to $\dot p_C$ and solve this in Simulink.
So I used the quadratic solution formula.

$0=x^2+px+q \to x_{1,2}=-\frac{p}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q}$

Now I'm not sure. Am I allowed to do that at this differential equation?

Comment: Some first simulations show, that my approach get some good looking results

Answer (score 0):

Sure, as long as you actually want to find the x-intercepts of the differentiated equation, or rather turning points of the original equation